# Suggestions for matching spoken and written digits with Machine Learning

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, mnist

I’m working on a machine learning problem which is proving very difficult. I want to learn to recognize whether an image of a hand written digit and a recording of a spoken digit refer to the same or different number. False: the image and the recording refer to different numbers and True: the image and the recording refer to the same number.

**The Data:**

Each image is given as 784-dimensional vector, which represents 28x28 pixel grayscale image. The pixel intensities range from 0 (black) to 255 (white). 
Each sound recording of a spoken name of a digit (e.g. “zero”, “one’ etc, pronounced in Arabic) is given as an array of pre-extracted audio features, so called Mel-Frequency Cepstral Coefficients (MFCC). These features encode the charachteristics of a 10 milisecond frame of speech. Each recording is of variable length, and thus each example is given as an array of shape (N, 13), where N is the number of frames in the recording, and 13 the number of MFCC features.

For this problem I got 5 datasets:

- Written_train.npy: array with 45,000 rows and 784 columns
- Written_test.npy: array with 15,000 rows and 784 columns
- Spoken_train.npy: array with 45,000 rows. Each row Is an object of shape (N, 13)
- Spoken_test.npy: array with 15,000 rows. Each row is an object of shape (N, 13)
- Match_train.nyp: array with 45,000 boolean values (False or True)

Notice that there aren't any labels for the written and spoken digits.

In sum: I want to create an array of 15000 boolean values, specifying whether the images and sounds from the test data matched or not.

**Current Approaches:**

One approach I have tried implementing was clustering both spoken and written data, and then training a classifier to see what clusters match. However, I do not have a way of checking if the clustering is accurate in the audio data.

Another approach I'm trying is combining both data sets to feed into a MLP. Here however, I am not sure how to approach combining the data.

Finally, I also found an article describing a network that combines mixed data: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/

**Do you recommend proceeding with one of the approaches mentioned above? Or is there a different/simpler method I am missing.**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this will be two run two models. One to recognize the image and this model could be convolutional neural network. You will be able to find several CNN examples for number recognition.

The second part of your solution will be to use RNN or any simple word recognition library to classify the spoken number. You will find enough examples for this too.

the last task will be to compare the prediction from both the model and see if they match. To do this, store predictions into list for models and then use whatever evaluation metric you want to use on that.